# International space station(ISS) viewed from planet earth

Tags: artificial-satellite, space-telescope, telescope

Is it possible to view International space station (ISS) using sophisticated Telescopes from planet earth?[image]

Comment: You seem to have a habit of asking very basic questions while doing very little, if any research. Opening the webpages in the links you provided would have given you answers. The [NASA website](https://www.nasa.gov/vision/space/travelinginspace/f_skywatch.html) clearly states the ISS can be seen from one's backyard. It also states "The Space Station is one of the most visible man made objects in the sky". If an orbiting or celestial object can be seen with an unaided eye it can be seen via a telescope. More effort from you would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Fred. I mean the ISS can be viewed using sophisticated Telescopes with more details & clearer as compared to with human eyes?

Comment: By simply searching "telescope ISS" or "telescope backyard ISS" you get lots of images, and even articles on how you can view the ISS yourself with a telescope.

Comment: Thanks Marc & Fred for the inputs provided.

Comment: Given that the purpose of a telescope is to see something in more detail than the human eye alone you've answered this already. This question has no purpose.

Comment: As per GdD's comment, this question has no purpose. Please familiarise yourself with how Stack Exchange works, at our [ask] and [about] pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need a telescope. You can see it with the naked eye.

> Is it possible to view ISS using sophisticated telescopes from planet earth?

And per [@GdD's comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/international-space-stationiss-viewed-from-planet-earth#comment185170_55437):

> Given that the purpose of a telescope is to see something in more detail than the human eye alone you've answered this already. This question has no purpose.

Comment: feel free to roll back, I just thought that this might help